# Databiding in parameters with Angular4

Tags: angular, bitcoin

Im trying to generate a QR code with the corresponent bitcoin address and the amount. The problem is that I want to change dinamically the address and the amount of the QR Code.

Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-qrcode to generate the QR Code, and I want to bind data into the parameters of the tag. I'll write the code as an example so I can explain myself clearer.

This is the code right now:

```
<div>
      <qr-code [value]="'bitcoin:1MoLoCh1srp6jjQgPmwSf5Be5PU98NJHgx?amount=.01'" [size]="150"></qr-code>
    </div>
```

I tried to do it this way but its not working:

```
<div>
      <qr-code [value]="'bitcoin:{{bitcoinAddress}}?amount={{transactionAmount}}'" [size]="150"></qr-code>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/SuperiorJT/angular2-qrcode/issues/10#issuecomment-277293389

Comment: try using the adding ngModel under the qr-code tag like <qr-code [value]="{{bitcoin adder}}" ngModel></qr-code>

Comment: Test it: `value="bitcoin:{{bitcoinAddress}}?amount={{transactionAmount}}"` or... `[value]="'bitcoin:' + bitcoinAddress + '?amount=' + transactionAmount"`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I still cant figure out how to do it. I tried all your replies... but not working

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. I declared a new variable called dataBitcoin and then bind it into the html.

Here is the code

component.ts

```
private bitcoinAddress = '12z3Uu6Gj8DjA4ADna9Dbe9aZRmZnRnfmL';
private transactionAmount‌ = 2;

bitcoinData = "bitcoin:" + this.bitcoinAddress + "?amount=" + this.transactionAmount‌;
```

html

```
<qr-code [value]="bitcoinData" [size]="150"></qr-code>
```